# Error remove parent using jQuery in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I wrote a jQuery function to add and remove some input, but I got this error, pls help me !
I using jQuery 3.2.1 and Laravel 5.4

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined***

**Here is my view:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add').click(function () {
                var tr = '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<label for="title">Title</label>' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" value="{{ old('title') }}">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<label for="body">Body</label>' +
                    '<textarea class="form-control" rows="10"  name="body[]" value="{{ old('title') }}"></textarea>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x">';
                $('.info').append(tr);
            });
            $('.info').on('click', '.delete', function () {
                $(this).parent.parent.remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
        <h1>Create a post</h1>
        <hr>
        <form method="post" action="/blog/posts">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x">
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary add" value="Add New Item">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Publish</button>
        </form>
        @include('layouts.errors')
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: it's saying that $(this).parent.parent.remove(); parent.parent doesn't exists.

Comment: First of all place you <script> tag under the html code and try `$(this).parent().remove();`

Comment: your input has only one parent presumably, what does `console.log($(this).parent());` show? you can as well insert `debugger;` before the `remove` operation line, activate your code inspector and debug [step by step](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove that `currently clicked` element `parent div` but you have common parent div for all elements so it's removing all elements . so `wrap` the each set of element to `new div`  `var tr = '<div class="new">.... </div>` . so that you can easily remove `specific div` only  take a look on my snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add').click(function () {
                 var tr = '<div class="new"><div class="form-group">' +
                    '<label for="title">Title</label>' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" value="">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<label for="body">Body</label>' +
                    '<textarea class="form-control" rows="10"  name="body[]" value=""></textarea>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"> </div>';
                $('.info').append(tr);
            });
            $('.info').on('click', '.delete', function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
        <h1>Create a post</h1>
        <hr>
        <form method="post" action="/blog/posts">
            <div class="info">
               
                <div class="new">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"> 
            </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary add" value="Add New Item">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Publish</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :) Bro @ManhNguyen

Answer (score 2):

Change from

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $(this).parent.parent.remove();
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole HTML which you are trying to append should be one div. So your code should look like this.

```
  var tr = '<div class="parent-div"><div class="form-group">' +
               '<label for="title">Title</label>' +
               '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" value="{{ old('title') }}">' +
               '</div>' +
               '<div class="form-group">' +
               '<label for="body">Body</label>' +
               '<textarea class="form-control" rows="10"  name="body[]" value="{{ old('title') }}"></textarea>' +
               '</div>' +
               '<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"></div>';
```

And than replace your code with this

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(this).closest("input").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
   $(this).parents('.info').empty();
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
   $(this).parents('.info').remove();
});
```